# How to set Log4perl log level on the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, log4perl

Is it possible to set the log level globally for Log4perl by passing a command line flag or setting an environment variable (and not changing the original logging setup)? The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.49/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm) and [FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html) don't seem to mention any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use somthing like this:

```perl
Log::Log4perl->get_logger()->level(
    Log::Log4perl::Level::to_priority($ENV{APP_LOG_LEVEL})
);
```

and run script:

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG perl app.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the configuration file syntax to define your appenders (note that you don't have to place this into a real file; you can also have the configuration definition inside your program), you already have environment variable substitution out of the box. See the section named "Variable Substitution" in the [Log4Perl documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.49/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm).

Comment: I specifically don't want to change the original logging setup, to avoid complicating the code base.